# npm pack doesn't include all files in the package

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-pack

I run `npm pack` inside `dist` folder, but it doesn't include all it's files.
it just contains: package.json, ReADME.md, index.js (main).

there is no `.gitignore` file, and I tried to create an empty `.npmignore` file, but it didn't help.

I also tried to add `files` array to `package.json`.

all files in the root or subfolders (js or other files) don't included in the pack file.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. What's in the directory, and `package.json`? Do you see any information when you run `pack`? Etc.

Comment: thank you @jonrsharpe for your help, I will close this issue as it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found another `files` property in my `package.json`, so adding another one has no effect, also `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` have no effect.

Comment: `field` -> `files`? Yes, only one of those will be counted. And both `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` *reduce* the number of included files, so if the problem is having too few files of course they don't help.